# Python flask can't bring the db from mysql after starting a server.

Tags: python, mysql, flask

init code

```
@app.route('/illegal/')
@login_required
def illegal():
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM image')
    datas = c.fetchall()


    return render_template('illegal.html', datas = datas)
```

illegal.html

```
<tbody>
        {% for data in datas %}
        <tr>
            <td style="width:17%">{{data[1]}}</td>
            <td style="width:17%">{{data[2]}}</td>
            <td style="width:17">{{data[3]}}</td>
            <td style="width:17%">{{data[4]}}</td>
            <td style="width:25%"><img src={{data[5]}} style=" max-width:     80%; height: auto" class="img-rounded" width="100" hegiht="100"      ></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Imagine that there is 4 data in Mysql and then start the server. When I insert new data into table. My web doesn't know there is new one or not. It just know the original one that exist before starting the server. When I check the mysql, new data was inserted. but now exists in web server. If you know the solution, Please help me

Comment: You are not fetching data after you add a new record to the database. How do you insert a new record into the database?